# MapBox navigation remaining time

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

HI I am trying to implement `Mapbox` framework for navigation.

[MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/help/ios-navigation-sdk/#next-steps) Navigation is working fine. and I can get the estimated time to the destination working fine.
But, I need to show a slider during the journey. So, I want to receive remaining duration while travelling..
Is there a delegate methods available for the same?

Comment: did you get anything for that?

Comment: @emraz: Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

In the MapBox Delegate method,

```
func routeController(_ routeController: RouteController, didUpdate locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let reamingiTime = routeController.routeProgress.durationRemaining
    }
```

We can get the remaining time, by using this I changing my progress bar value